# Exception ResultSet is closed when using method next()

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

i'm having a trouble with the next() method when i try to insert a values to table from the the while(sr.next()) it throw ResultSet Exception but when i'm removing the insert query from the body of the while it work so why the ResultSet is closed when i'm training to insert values in the while body here is the code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SqlServerJDBC {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String line, dis;
        float totalPrice = 0;
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);

        try {
                    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                    System.out.println("# - Driver Loaded");

                    Connection con =               DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:books_DSN");
                    System.out.println("# - Connection Obtained");

                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    System.out.println("# - Statement Created");

                    String createTableOrder =  "create table viewOrder"
                                            + "(title_name VARCHAR(40),"
                                            + "price DECIMAL(5,2),"
                                            + "pages INT,"
                                            + "au_fname VARCHAR(15),"
                                            + "au_lname VARCHAR(15),"
                                            + "pub_name VARCHAR(20),"
                                            + "city VARCHAR(15),"
                                            + "country VARCHAR(15))";



                    stmt.executeUpdate(createTableOrder);
                    System.out.println("Created table in given database...");

                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT title_name,price FROM titless");
                    System.out.println("# - Query Executed\n");

                    while(rs.next()){
                        System.out.println("title: " +rs.getString("title_name") + "\tprice: " + rs.getFloat("price"));             
                    }   

                        do {
                            System.out.println("\nEnter the name of the book...");
                            line = scan.nextLine();
                            rs = stmt.executeQuery("select title_name,price,pages,au_fname"
                                    + ",au_lname,pub_name,authorss.city,country "
                                    + " from titless inner join title_authorss on titless.title_id = title_authorss.title_id "
                                    + " inner join authorss on title_authorss.au_id = authorss.au_id"
                                    + " inner join publisherss on publisherss.pub_id = titless.pub_id"
                                    + " where titless.title_name like "+"'"+line+"'");


                            /*here is the problem */
                                while(rs.next()){

                                String insertIntoTableOrder =("INSERT INTO viewOrder "
                                        + " VALUES ('"+rs.getString("title_name")+"',"+rs.getFloat("price")+","+rs.getInt("pages")+""
                                        + ",'"+rs.getString("au_fname")+"','"+rs.getString("au_lname")+"',"
                                        + "'"+rs.getString("pub_name")+"','"+rs.getString("city")+"','"+rs.getString("country")+"')");
                                stmt.executeUpdate(insertIntoTableOrder);

                                totalPrice = totalPrice + rs.getFloat("price"); 


                            }


                            System.out.println("Total Price = " + totalPrice);
                            System.out.println("Do you want add more books ??");
                            System.out.println("Y/N...");
                            dis = scan.nextLine();


                        } while (dis.equalsIgnoreCase("y")); 



                         con.close();
                         stmt.close();   
                         rs.close();

                    System.out.println("# - Resources released");

                } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                            System.out.println("Error : "+ex);
           }

    }   

  }
```

[image: here is the output]

Comment: you close your while loop before even to get e chance to get rs.next()

Comment: It seems that you are running executeQuery on the same ResultSet object while inside the rs.next while loop. Is there a reason for this? Maybe if you used a different ResultSet object it would solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

As per the docs:

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an open one exists.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html

You're iterating through your `ResultSet` and reusing the same `Statement` to do your `INSERT`. As soon as you execute the insert, the `ResultSet` you're iterating through is closed, and the next call  to `rs.next()` throws that exception. You would need to use a new `Statement` to execute your insert query inside the loop.

That said, you really should be using prepared statements for your SQL. It's cleaner in terms of reading your code, and far less error prone as they handle any necessary quoting for you.

```
String statementString = "INSERT INTO viewOrder VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement pStmt= con.prepareStatement(statementString);
while(rs.next())
{
    pStmt.setString(1, rs.getString("title_name"));
    pStmt.setFloat(2, rs.getFloat("price"));
    pStmt.setInt(3, rs.getInt("pages"));
    pStmt.setString(4, rs.getString("au_fname"));
    pStmt.setString(5, rs.getString("au_lname"));
    pStmt.setString(6, rs.getString("pub_name"));
    pStmt.setString(7, rs.getString("city"));
    pStmt.setString(8, rs.getString("country"));
    pStmt.execute();

    totalPrice = totalPrice + rs.getFloat("price"); 
}
```

Comment: seems also not be the problem. Because in this case you just a get some kind of database resource exception. Next to it i think there must be somekind of logical problem.

Comment: Erm, no ... he's doing exactly what I said, and receiving the exact exception one would expect. There's no "logical problem" If he were to use a separate Statement for his insert, it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need another Statement object. Invoking a second query on your singular Statement, while iterating a ResultSet (which is tied to a cursor on **that same** statement) is a bad idea.